# Jquery Datable plugin not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, datatable, html-table

I've a tabe and want to use jquery datable plugin in that code and it is not working.I have tried downloading the javascript and css file and using those. heplp me to find a solution. here is my code.

```
<script src="required/jquery-3.2.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />   

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="example">
    <tr>
        <th>Question:</th>
        <th>option1</th>
        <th>option2</th>
        <th>option3</th>
        <th>option4</th>
        <th>Right option</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>Who is the father of science?</td>
        <td>Sir Issac Newton</td>
        <td>Albert Einstein</td>
        <td>Michel Farady</td>
        <td>Robert Hook</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Edit Delete</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Who is father of computer?</td>
        <td>Charles Babbage</td>
        <td>Lady Ada </td>
        <td>Blaise Pascal</td>
        <td>Bill Gates</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Edit Delete</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>rame</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>s</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Edit Delete</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>q</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Edit Delete</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#example').DataTable();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Is there an error in your navigator's console ?

Comment: yes it says 'c' is undefined in   jquery.dataTables.min.js:90:237
how can i solve this??

Comment: @prashantkandel You should edit your post to include information about the error you've received, and what the expected behavior is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<thead>` is not available in your table. Just add the header in `thead` and try

```
<thead>
        <th>Question:</th>
        <th>option1</th>
        <th>option2</th>
        <th>option3</th>
        <th>option4</th>
        <th>Right option</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </thead>
```